# Wordpress Featured Image function recreate

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am facing a problem of recreating a featured image function to show different images in different section.
I was trying to modify the existing function "Featured Image" and duplicate the post meta box but I am failed...

Could any one help me to sort this out, or give me an idea of how could I set up the Image meta box which I could apply to different page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution by myself...
I was installing a plugin called "Multiple Post Thumbnails"
That is really quite useful...

Answer (score 0):

wordpress 2.9.2 and up has a build in function for post-thumbnails
you can use that and you can read about it here

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
- http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/11/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-wordpress-2-9s-post-image-feature

Comment: Unfortunately i don't think that's what Panda was asking, i believe Panda knows about the existing functionality, and is trying to emulate that inside his/her own plugin(or custom code) thats run inside WordPress.